# Which array/list should I use?

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures, types

I am looking for a list type which implement the following feature (pseudocode):

```
 list.init(5, 2, 6, 9);
 list.add(1) // 2, 6, 9, 1
 list.add(4) // 6, 9, 1, 4
 list.add(8) // 9, 1, 4, 8
```

Add new element to fixed size list and pop the oldest one.
I am sorry, I don´t know the name of this concept so I asking you, what the name could be. ;)

My implementation in C++ would be actually this:

```
std::deque<double> values(4);

void add(double value)
{
    values.pop_front();
    values.push_back(value);
}
```

Are there any better implementations than mine, maybe alltime fixed size?

Comment: You may look at *circular buffer* or *ring buffer* or *cyclic buffer*

Comment: STL has no container that emulates fixed size circular buffer, sorry. But I would be very surprised if Boost doesn't have one, or you can build it over either `std::array` (smallish collections that don't leave scope) or `std::vector` (everything else).

Comment: @Xarn: [Boost circular buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Boost's circular_buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/circular_buffer.html) is what you want.

Example of usage:

```
   boost::circular_buffer<int> buffer(3);
   buffer.push_back(1);
   buffer.push_back(2);
   buffer.push_back(3);
   // now buffer is 1, 2, 3
   buffer.push_back(4);
   // now buffer is 2, 3, 4
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/250586c7133daa84)

Answer (score 13):

What you want is called circular buffer. There is no such container in the STL, but [Boost does have an implementation.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/circular_buffer.html)

If you don't want to pull in huge dependency on Boost, you can quite easily implement a wrapper over either [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (if the number of element is smallish) or over [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

The wrapper needs to remember the underlying container size and it's current position, like this:

```
template <class T>
class circular_buffer {
    std::size_t current_pos, cursor;
    std::vector<T> storage;

    circular_buffer(std::size_t size):current_pos(0), cursor(0){
        storage.resize(size);
    }

    void push_back(T elem){
        storage[current_pos++] = T;
        if (current_pos == storage.size()){
            current_pos = 0;
        }
    }

    T get_element(){
        if (cursor == storage.size()){
            cursor = 0;
        }
        return storage[cursor++];
    }

};
```

*Note that the example is simplified and doesn't implement things like second template argument if using `std::array`, or what to do if your cursor and insertion position catch up to each other.*

Comment: Would your implementation not be like: current circle = 4 1 5; add 7 -> 7 1 5; add 9 -> 7 9 5 but I wanted: 4 1 5 -> 1 5 7 -> 5 7 9

Comment: @Viatorus The trick is in `get_element`, give me a sec to edit it in.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write you own queue with limited interface.like this

```
template<class T, class Cont = deque<T> >
class MyQueue: protected queue<T,Cont>
{
public:
    MyQueue(size_type size, const T& t=T())
    {
        while(size--)
        {
            c.push_back(t);
        }
    }

    void pop_push(const value_type& x)
    {
        pop();
        __super::push(x);
    }
};
```

It's protected  inheritance,so you can't change its size.

Answer (score -1):

You could try boost's circular buffer.

Comment: Have you thought of boost's circular buffer?

Comment: There's no point in repeating what the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25421528/827263) already says.